# Chaining user responses with SQL Server and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm not quite sure how to approach this so thought it best to ask, see if anyone has any ideas that may help.

I have a table stored in SQL Server that stores Exchange 2010 Mailbox Server Performance Data with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[2010_Perfmon_MBX]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Server] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ObjectName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CounterName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [InstanceName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Value] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NULL
)
```

I also have an ASP.NET website written in C#. I want to allow users to select cascading answers, that ultimately returns the requested data into a GridView/Graph.

Right now, my main challenge is how to ensure the data is not returned until the end user has selected values from all of the columns.

I want to stage it like this:

User is asked for a server to pull data from

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Server)
FROM 2010_Perfmon_MBX
```

Let's pretend they pick the server `MailboxServer.domain.com`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ObjectName)
FROM 2010_Perfmon_MBX
WHERE Server = 'MailboxServer.domain.com'
```

User is then asked, based on the server `MailboxServer.domain.com`, for an ObjectName. They pick `'msexchangeis mailbox'` for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CounterName)
FROM 2010_Perfmon_MBX
WHERE Server = 'MailboxServer.domain.com'
AND ObjectName = 'msexchangeis mailbox'
```

Next the user is asked for `CounterName`. They pick `'active rpc threads'`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(InstanceName)
FROM 2010_Perfmon_MBX
WHERE Server = 'MailboxServer.domain.com'
AND ObjectName = 'msexchangeis mailbox'
AND CounterName = 'active rpc threads'
```

Lastly they pick the `InstanceName`. In this example `'Database20'`. The full query then runs which pulls back all of the data based on the choices made:

```
SELECT *
FROM 2010_Perfmon_MBX
WHERE Server = 'MailboxServer.domain.com'
AND ObjectName = 'msexchangeis mailbox'
AND CounterName = 'active rpc threads'
AND InstanceName = 'Database20'
```

What is the most elegant way of ensuring that the flow of choices works without jumping ahead and chaining the selections?

I need to ensure that the selections are dynamic, and is based on available data in the SQL Server table for the selected server, so only valid data can be chosen.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a broad question so here's a broad answer. I will assume your web-application is ASP.NET WebForms.

1. Use DropDownList controls for user selection, use RequiredFieldValidator controls to ensure the user makes a valid selection from each one.
2. Bind the dropdownlists with your SELECT DISTINCT data
3. Have a submit Button, on post-back check Page.IsValid and if true, get the data and bind the GridView.

**Update**

Ok I think you're saying the available choices depend on the previous one, starting with the server. In that case present each DropDownList (make visible) one at a time, set their autopostback property to true. Each time index changes re-bind all subsequent dependent DropDownLists. You can also use validator controls to ensure the user has made a selection in all lists before submitting:

aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlObjectName" runat="server" DataSourceId="dsObjectName" 
    OnDataBound="ddlObjectName_DataBound"></DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ddlObjectNameRequired" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="ddlObjectName" InitialValue="-1"
        ErrorMessage="Please select an Object Name.">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" />
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void ddlObjectName_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlObjectName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select...", "-1"));
}

protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.IsValid)
    {
        //Bind the data grid ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup your Update has hit the nail on the head. My DDL's will all be individually bound to a datasource, but I need to ensure they don't databind until the previous one has been databound, and had an index change as well. I guess that's what I'm struggling with at the moment. I will have a play about as soon as I can do so, it may be tomorrow though!

Comment: If you're using ObjectDataSource's or SqlDataSources you can make one of the parameters a ControlParameter with the ID of the dependant DropDownList

Comment: OK Holly, I've created an .ASPX page that allows me to select server(s), select the 3 different counter types (ObjectName, CounterName, InstanceName). I need to stop it retrieving the data at each step until i'm ready though. Right now if I fill in a Server and click the button, it goes and completes all of the other dropdowns and starts returning data. What's the best way to stop this? I want another button to retrieve the data once it's ready.

Comment: With out having your actual web application in front of me I can't possibly say what the best solution is. But one way of doing it is to use validator controls, see  my edited answer.

Comment: I will give you the answer for trying to help out. Thanks Holly! In the end I created 3 DDL's, 3 Object Data Sources. Configured each DDL to be unbound at runtime, then when a server is selected, bound only DDL 1 to the ODS. On Index Changed I then bound DDL 2. On Index change on that DDL 3. After all the DDLs are populated with choices, the user can click an ASP button which binds another ODS to a GV. Everything seems to work OK with this :)